# Trying to printf a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

Hi guys I'm really confused with this one, basically what I'm trying to do is take an input and save it in a string array and then print whatever I wrote down in the string array.  Instead of printf displaying what I wrote down it gives me weird characters.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char string[100];
printf("hey put a string here\n");
scanf("[%s\n]", string);
printf("hey this is what you wrote \n");
printf(string);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What did you expect from the format string `"[%s\n]"`?

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but `printf(string);` should be `printf("%s", string)`, or perhaps `printf("%s\n", string);` -- or just `puts(string);`.  By passing user input data to `printf` as the format string, you risk arbitrarily bad consequences if the string happens to contain a `%` character.

Comment: You didn't initialise `string`, or test the return value from `scanf`, so the output is garbage.

Comment: learn to use a debugger, you can then see if the problem is reading string in or printing string out. https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/

Comment: Look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack) for an  article explaining why you should NEVER `printf(string)` unless `string` is a compile time constant. There are several vulnerabilities that can be exposed this way, especially with the use of `%n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using

```
scanf("[%s\n]", string);
```

to read a line of text, use `fgets`.

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```

Also, the line:

```
printf(string);
```

will not print the contents of `string` if `string` contains anything that can be a format for `printf`. If `string` is `"abcd %d"`, then `printf` will expect an `int` as the second argument. Instead of that, use:

```
printf("%s", string);
```